# How does the NFA decide in a state where there are multiple equally valid "next states"?

Tags: automata, nondeterminism

How does the NFA decide in a state where there are multiple equally valid "next states"?

Such as here:
[image]

How does it decide on which state it takes to with 1?

Comment: Or perhaps this implies to always convert to the equivalent DFA?

Comment: It doesn't decide. It tries all legal trajectories, and accepts if at least one of them ends at an accepting state.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus But what if both p and q were accepting states? It may sound like redundant, but I'm actually having such case here. That the same input leads to **two different accepting states**.

Comment: Then nothing special happens. It still tries all legal trajectories.

Comment: @mavavilj Read and understand the definition of NFAs. If you don't understand the definition, figure out _what_ you don't understand and ask a question about that. But what you're asking here is an extremely basic question.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus What if it's an "attribute grammar", where the two different accepting states lead to "different output actions"? So they aren't equivalent, even if the input leads to both?

Comment: @mavavilj Then it's probably deterministic, or has explicit tie-breaking rules.

Comment: Your new example doesn't look like an NFA at all.

Comment: @mavavilj That's the point: automata don't model boolean statements. And a transition on an automaton is labeled by an event, not by a verb. Your Lennon diagram read as an automaton does not have any natural meaning, certainly not the ones you describe.

Comment: Removed the other example as being unclear.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It doesn't decide. Nondeterminism isn't intended to be a realistic model of computation. Check the definition: a nondeterministic automaton accepts if there's any valid sequence of transitions that reach an accepting state.

Answer (score 4):

**NFA**

The nondeterminism arises from the fact that there are multiple choices for possible next states due to multiple edges for the same input and epsilon ($\epsilon$) transitions. There is no sensor that indicates which state is actually chosen.

The interpretation often given in the theory of computation is that when there are multiple choices, the machine clones itself and one copy runs each choice. It is like having multiple universes in which each different possible action of nature is occurring simultaneously. If there are no outgoing edges for a certain combination of state and input, then the clone dies.

Comment: Actually, I've never seen the "cloning" interpretation presented as anything other than an informal intuition. The formal definition is always in terms of the existence of an accepting path.

Comment: just go through this, Hope it will help you : http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/node558.html

Comment: Cloning Interpretation is mentioned here too : http://internetnotes.in/toc/   .I have posted the sources,  I hope my answer is justifiable now and if not please do let me know,Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It can be seen as parallel computation wherein multiple processes can be running concurrently. An NFA splits into these different paths non-deterministically and will accept a word if at least one of these paths accept

Comment: Disregarding the fact that the question is seven years old, I wonder why you emphasize a split "non-deterministically" rather than exhaustively ?